# Remove "clear filter" option from the column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, filter

I’ve connected SpListFilterWebPart filter to the list and it works fine filtering the list except that I can’t clear filter selection. That is, once filter is applied to the list, little “filter” icon appears on the filtered column. Once I click on it, drop down appears with “Clear Filter from...” option. i want to remove this option.

[image: here is the screenshot...]

Any help?

Comment: can you paste some HTML code which is getting generated for this option, we might be able to hide this option via jquery. For that please edit your question with html which is getting generated for for this dropdown. You can use developer tool to get this html

Comment: And if is possible, could you post a printscreen pointing where is the option that you want to remove.

Comment: No need for jQuery, target it with a higher Specificity CSS selector

Comment: @ThalesChemenian i have shared the screenshot of my listview. i dont want to show that filter icon or in other words i want to disable filtering for users

Answer (score 2):

Add `Script Editor WebPart/Content Editor WebPart` on listview page.
Add following css in webpart.

```
<style>
.ms-listviewtable li[class="ms-core-menu-item"]:nth-child(n+3) {
  display:none !important;   
}
</style>
```